# Error en mi consola nodejs address already in use :::3700

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

verán, tengo un problema con la consola en mi proyecto node. Estoy tratando de hacer las operaciones de crud a través de clientes rest como postman. Las operaciones me las está realizando bien pero en la consola me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como les decía ahora, se está inroduciendo normal a la base de datos mongo pero ese error no desaparece de la consola y cuando quiero ver los datos por esta no se puede. De todos modos aquí les dejo mi conexión que al parecer es donde está el detalle que este error menciona:

```
    /* Conexón a la base de datos con node */
'use strict';

/* Creamos una variable y almacenamos en un objeto moongose */
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
/* Llamar a las variables que tenemos en nuestro archivo app */
var app=require('./app');
var port=3700;

/* Conexion a la base de datos */

/* Le decimos a mongoose que haremos la conexion mediante promesas--- */
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.Promise=global.Promise;
/* Usamos el método connect para conectar------- */
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/portafolio',{ useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(()=>{
    console.log('Conexión a la base de datos...');
    /* Ejecutar la creación del servidor */
    app.listen(port,()=>{
        console.log('Servidor correcto en local 3700');
    })

})
.catch(error=> console.log(error));
```

Comment: el puerto `3700` ya lo tienes en uso, busca el id del proceso que esta usando ese puerto y matalo. puedes usar `sudo lsof -t -i:3700` y despues `sudo kill -9 <ID>`

Comment: Isaac héroe sin capa. Gracias bro